# Solve $\sum_i a_i b_i^n = k$ for $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve in closed form

$\sum_i a_i b_i^n = k$

for $n$,

with $a_i, b_i, k>0$ ?

Comment: The question is unclear. Over what are we summing? Can we choose both $a_i,b_j$?

Comment: @b00nheT $a_i$, $b_i$, $k$ are given constants, the sum is over some $i$s, more precisely $\sum_{i=1}^M (a_i b_i^n)$. Does that clarify everything?

Comment: Sure. Well, as far as I know, the answer is no. Try solving
$$2^n+3^n=4,$$
this very simple special case already gives you enough trouble, so I wouldn't expect any general closed form.